problems when using Dask in a Dataframe in Python
A newbie here using parallel computing in Phyton
I have ~80 huge CSV files (32 GB each) that I need to process in Python to retrieve some rows from them.
The file structure is
 'Barra', 'D1', 'D2','D3','D4','D5','D6','D7','D8','CMG'

One possibility is to translate all the csv to a database but I would like to explore the use of Dask to process it (if the processing time is over 20 min for all files probably I will switch to a database if it is faster).
I have the following code but doesn't work :(
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter import ttk
filename1 = fd.askopenfilename(title="ARCHIVO CSV ENTRADA")
filename2 = fd.asksaveasfile(initialfile = 'Untitled.csv', defaultextension=".csv", title="ARCHIVO DE SALIDA")
dt1=datetime.now()
barra=['barra1','barra3','barra5','barra7','barra9','barra11','barra13','barra15','barra17','barra19']
ichunk=1
def Proceso(chunk_df,barra):
    # Proceso de elecciòn
    chunk_df.columns = ['ID', 'barra', 'D1', 'D2','D3','D4','D5','D6','D7','D8','CMG']
    chunk1 = chunk_df[chunk_df['barra'].isin(barra)]
    return chunk1
for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename1, chunksize=100000):
    chunk_df = dd.from_pandas(chunk, npartitions=5)
    chunk1_df = chunk_df.map_partitions(chunk_df,barra).compute()
    chunk1.to_csv(filename2.name, index=False, mode='a', header=False)
    print("pasada:", ichunk)
    ichunk=ichunk+1
dt2=datetime.now()
print("FIN: ",dt2-dt1)

Dask leaves the following message:
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[12], line 21
     19 for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename1, chunksize=100000):
     20     chunk_df = dd.from_pandas(chunk, npartitions=5)
---> 21     chunk1_df = chunk_df.map_partitions(chunk_df,barra).compute()
     22     chunk1.to_csv(filename2.name, index=False, mode='a', header=False)
     23     print("pasada:", ichunk)

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py:1006, in _Frame.map_partitions(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    878 @insert_meta_param_description(pad=12)
    879 def map_partitions(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
    880     """Apply Python function on each DataFrame partition.
    881 
    882     Note that the index and divisions are assumed to remain unchanged.
   (...)
   1004     None as the division.
   1005     """
-> 1006     return map_partitions(func, self, *args, **kwargs)

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py:6924, in map_partitions(func, meta, enforce_metadata, transform_divisions, align_dataframes, *args, **kwargs)
   6921 name = kwargs.pop("token", None)
   6922 parent_meta = kwargs.pop("parent_meta", None)
-> 6924 assert callable(func)
   6925 if name is not None:
   6926     token = tokenize(meta, *args, **kwargs)

AssertionError: 

At the moment without Dask the process time for one file is ~8 min and I need to reduce this to the minimum possible.
I'm using chunks to avoid memory problems (old structure without Dask). Can I take out this part when I use Dask?
Any ideas to solve the error?
Thanks!

The 1st parameter of map_partitions() should be a function not a df.

Thanks for the help! now is working OK. time was reduced from 9 min to 4 min

Also, with Dask, if all your csv files have the same structure, you shouldn't have to open them sequentially, you could build a lazy big dataframe on all the csv file and filter them!
